# Access violation writing location in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, access-violation, irvine32

Hi i have a question about assembly x86

this is my code

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
day WORD 0
month WORD 0
year WORD 0


prompt1 BYTE "enter month: ",0
prompt2 BYTE "enter day: ",0
prompt3 BYTE "enter an year: ",0
prompt4 BYTE " the day of the week is ",0

.code
main PROC

mov edx, OFFSET prompt1
call writeString
mov edx, 0
call readInt
call crlf
mov month, ax

mov eax, 0
mov edx, OFFSET prompt2
call writeString
mov edx, 0
call readInt
call crlf
mov day, ax


mov eax, 0
mov edx, OFFSET prompt3
call writeString
mov edx, 0
call readInt
call crlf
mov year, ax



mov eax, 0
mov ebx, 0
mov ax, 14
sub ax, month
mov bx, 12
div bx
mov si, ax ;; a store in si
sub year, ax
mov di, year ;; y store in di
mov ax, ax
mul bx
add ax, month
mov cx, 2
sub ax, cx
mov ecx, 0
mov cx, ax ;; m store in cx

mov eax, 0
mov ebx, 0
mov esp, 0
mov ebp, 0

add day, di
mov ax, di
mov bx, 4
div bx
add day, ax
mov sp, day
mov eax, 0
mov ebx, 0
mov ax, di
mov bl, 100
div bl
mov ah, 0
sub day, ax


mov eax, 0
mov ebx, 0
mov dx, 0
mov ax, di
mov bx, 400
div bx
add day, ax
mov bp, day  ;; temporary holder for d value up to y/400 calculation

mov eax, 0
mov ebx, 0
mov ax, 31
mul cx
mov bx, 12
div bx
add bp, ax
mov al, 7
div al




    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

I' m debugging this code everything seems to work accordingly, until I reach the exit instruction then visual studio gave me this error " Access violation writing location 0x000009DF",  I a bit confused that it gave me this error at the end of the code, why would there be access violation at the exit command

this is my input

```
enter month: 4

enter day: 15

enter an year: 2013
```

At the end of the program i get value of register al = 1 which is what i want 
so I don't know why it gave me this error when there is no other error in the code 
can anyone help ?
thank in advance

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found the error. It is this line:

```
mov sp, day
```

I did not set `esp` to zero before this, that’s why the program shows an access violation.

Comment: This is not correct. Setting the destination register before you set it cannot possibly have anything to do with an access violation. The access violation is almost certainly caused by a *previous* instruction that accesses `esp`. Although I’m not sure why zeroing it would help. Accessing the memory at address 0 is not going to be particularly useful.

Comment: The question *does* have a `mov esp, 0` before this instruction.  In fact (**and overwriting the stack pointer with temporary data** at all!!) is probably *why* you later get a fault, perhaps when `call exit` tries to store a return address to `[esp]`.

Answer (score 0):

For to access to a ram location please use brackets, because it is easier to read.

```
 mov [year], ax

 mov di, [year]
```

And it is better for to prevent a missunderstanding the code, because if we use

```
mov di, year
```

it can be missenterprete with

```
mov di, offset year
```

because if we use NASM instead of MASM, then this instruction do not need the offset declaration for to get the offset address. NASM never interpret the instruction of

```
mov di, year
```

as an acces to a ram location.

.....

Normaly the stackpointer (E)SP is only for to use our stack.
If we use a call instruckton, then the address of the caller will be pushed on the Stack, so if we use a ret instrucktion at the end of this subroutine, then the address will be popped from the stack and the programmcounter will be set to the next instruction after the call instruction.

But if we do not use the stack for a moment, then we can save the address of the stackpointer to a ram location for to free use also the stackpointer.
At the end we can get the old address back from the ram location into the stackpointer.

Hint: Using (E)SP or E(BP) inside of an instruction as an addressregister the standard segmentregister is "SS" and not "DS".

```
mov [bp], ax   ; SS:BP
mov [sp], ax   ; SS:SP
mov ax, [bp]   ; SS:BP
mov ax, [sp]   ; SS:SP

mov [si], ax   ; DS:SI
mov [di], ax   ; DS:DI
mov [bx], ax   ; DS:BX
mov ax, [si]   ; DS:SI
mov ax, [di]   ; DS:DI
mov ax, [bx]   ; DS:BX
```

..

I do not know why this access violation appears. But, i do not think that this can be fixed with setting ESP to zero before using SP. I think it is bettter to save the address of the stackpointer before and get this address back at the end.

Dirk

Comment: This is 32-bit code; overwriting ESP with some random data (not pointer) value will obviously lead to a fault!  I'm guessing the OP doesn't know that (E)SP is the stack pointer.  Your examples with 16-bit addressing modes are not useful for an Irvine32 question, and `[sp]` isn't valid anyway.  `[esp]` is valid as a 32-bit addressing mode.